# Can import be used in Jakefiles?

Tags: jake

My editor is complaining that i.e. `task` is undefined, because it just treats `Jakefile`s as JavaScript.

Can I do something like this?

```
const { task } = require('jake')
task('default', () => {
  ...
```

(Also, is `Jakefile` the correct filename to use?)

Answer (score 0):

Tried it in Node.js v6, and it works.